# How to install a python package via yum without all the dependencies

Tags: python, couchdb, yum

I have already compiled couchdb 1.2 and I am using it. I now need to use couchdb python and I am trying to do yum install python-couchdb, but yum wants to install couchdb 1.1.1 because it propably doesnt find my compiled version. How can I tell yum to install only the python-couchdb package without the deps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python installs with easy_install for getting python eggs like python-couchdb. However, I and many people prefer a wrapper called PIP that allows better management of eggs.

[On linux you can install it like so.](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2010/02/how-install-pip-ubuntu/)

[Or if you prefer windows.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows)

Once you have pip you can install python-couchdb by calling:

```
sudo pip install couchdb
```

That shouldn't bork your couch installation.